# Dynamic input formatting in a JSP

Tags: jsp, input, formatting, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to design a JSP for my project's page. In one input field I need the user to be able to input a 16 digit number which gets separated into blocks of 4 digits as they type like so:

> 0000 0000 0000 0000

How do I make the space automatically add itself after every fourth digit while they type?

PS. I have a feeling JSTL will help but I've never used this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with JSTL or any java code.For solution you must use JavaScript.Jquery has Inputmask library for any masking of input.You can download library from here:https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether JSTL would do your help or not but you can do the same using javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    var len = x.length;
    if(len == 4 || len == 9 || len == 14)
    {
        x = x + " "; 
        document.getElementById("demo").value= x;
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="demo" onkeyup="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

I have not done any validation regarding whether the input field is number or not or whether it contains only 16 digits or not but I assume you will be able to do that using various other javascript methods.